# The elementary identities $a/(b\cdot c)=(a/b)/ c$ and $(a\cdot b)/c=a\cdot(b/c)$, what are they called in Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I suppose, the identities
$$
a/(b\cdot c)=(a/b)/c
$$
and 
$$
(a\cdot b)/c=a\cdot(b/c)
$$
must have special names in Algebra (like "distributivity", or "exponential law" for other identities). Can anybody enlighten me, which terms people use for them?

Comment: There probably aren't names because these identities aren't worth remembering. Personally I have never used these particular identities. The closest most useful one I can think of is $a/(b/c)=ac/b$. That one doesn't have a name either.

Comment: Thank you, rschwieb and @Arthur. I have a hope however that some terms are used somewhere for these situations. I am asking because these identities appear in category theory, see for example this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_space#Category_of_stereotype_spaces

Comment: The first identity is not even necessarily true, for example when the underlying multiplication is not commutative (e.g. when $a$, $b$ and $c$ are matrices). If the letters denote elements of an Abelian group, they follow from the axioms, commutativity and associativity and are not elementary.

Comment: I did not tell that these identities are true everywhere. I told that they are elementary having in mind that the usual multiplication and division of numbers have these properties.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov That means you should ask if the identities have a name in category theory. But it seems the answer to the "in algebra" version is "no."  You should probably also disclose you are the author of the content at the wiki article you linked to which you used to support your point.

Comment: @rschwieb I don't think that it's important who is the author. As to identities, I am sure that in category theory they don't have any names (although the first one can be called exponential property, but in different notations). It's much likely that in algebra (or in elementary number theory) people use some terms.

Comment: Following the algebra vs. category point: In algebra, one usually interprets $a/b$ as $a b^{-1}$ - in other words, division is not  an independent operation, and the identities trivially follow from the rules of multiplication (and don't merit a name). In your linked example, which deals with tensor products of spaces, the formulae is less trivial because it really involves two types of products which behave similar to ordinary multiplication and division.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov OK, I know you meant no harm, but I'm just saying that appealing to self-serving sources without disclosure might look bad to some readers.  Good luck finding your answers: regards

Comment: Hm... This is strange for me. OK, I am the author, and I need terms for using them in one of my papers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they have their own names.

You could, however, probably argue that the first one is a special case of exponents distributing over products (using the exponent $-1$):
$$
a\cdot (b\cdot c)^{-1} = a\cdot b^{-1}\cdot c^{-1}
$$
and the second law, if you swap out $a$ with $a/1$, is just applying the law for multiplying fractions:
$$
a\cdot \frac bc = \frac a1\cdot \frac bc = \frac{a\cdot b}{1\cdot c} = \frac{a\cdot b}c
$$
I am sure there are other laws you could use. For instance, the first one is also an instance of fraction expansion and simplification:
$$
\frac{a}{b\cdot c} = \frac{a/b}{b\cdot c / b} = \frac{a/b}{c}
$$
Also, I'm glad to see that you're using parentheses everywhere they are necessary, but using "$/$" for division when you don't have to just looks bad to me. Fractions and exponents are a lot easier to not not get wrong. Exceptions to this include exponents, limits of sums and integrals and such, where a fraction is just too large to fit, and another exponent becomes too small to read properly.